# Insert into one to many table with SP using linq to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have first table `Customers` and second table `CustomerContact` (one to many), so 1 company may have more than 1 key contacts.

I have created datacontext for both tables and created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNewCustomer]
    @CustoName VARCHAR (50),
    @Add1 VARCHAR (50),
    @Add2 VARCHAR (50),
    @City VARCHAR (50),
    @PostCOde VARCHAR (15),
    @County VARCHAR (30),
    @Country VARCHAR (30),
    @Rows int,
    @CustomerID INT,
    @Title VARCHAR(5),
    @FirstName VARCHAR(25),
    @LastName VARCHAR(25),
    @Designation VARCHAR(30),
    @LandLine VARCHAR(25),
    @Mobile VARCHAR(25),
    @Email VARCHAR(50),
    @FAX VARCHAR(25)
AS
    INSERT INTO Customers(CustName, Add1, Add2, City, PostCode, County, Country)
    VALUES(@CustoName, @Add1, @Add2, @City, @PostCOde, @County, @Country)

    SET @CustomerID = (SELECT MAX(@@IDENTITY) from Customers)

    WHILE @Rows IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO CustomerContact(CustomerID, Title, FirstName, LastName, Designation, LandLine, Mobile, Email, FAX)
        VALUES(@CustomerID, @Title, @FirstName, @LastName, @Designation, @LandLine, @Mobile, @Email, @FAX)
    END

    RETURN 0
```

now how do I pass all the parameters to SP using Linq-to-SQL I have tried this code but it shows an error

> CustomerID is not provided

while I am using CustomerID from the stored procedure.

```
Cust.CustName = companyName.Text;
Cust.Add1 = custAdd1txt.Text;
Cust.Add2 = custAdd2txt.Text;
Cust.City = custCitytxt.Text;
Cust.PostCode = custPostCodetxt.Text;
Cust.County = custCounty.Text;
Cust.Country = custCountry.Text;

custDC.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(Cust);
custDC.SubmitChanges();

for (int i = 0; i <= MyCustomers.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    custCont.Title = custKeyContactGV["Title", i].Value.ToString();
    custCont.FirstName = custKeyContactGV["FirstName", i].Value.ToString();
    custCont.LastName = custKeyContactGV["LastName", i].Value.ToString();
    custCont.Designation = custKeyContactGV["Designation", i].Value.ToString();
    custCont.LandLine = custKeyContactGV["Landline", i].Value.ToString();
    custCont.Mobile = custKeyContactGV["Mobile", i].Value.ToString();
    custCont.Email = custKeyContactGV["Email", i].Value.ToString();
    custCont.FAX = custKeyContactGV["FAX", i].Value.ToString();
}

custDC.CustomerContacts.InsertOnSubmit(custCont);
custDC.SubmitChanges();
```

Also I would like to pass Rows parameter into SP, it inserts data into customers but when it trys to insert into customercontact it shows error for CustomerID.

If I try to pass parameters it shows red line under SP (InsertNewCustomer) name, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
custDC.InsertNewCustomer(MyCustomers.CustomerName, MyCustomers.Address1, MyCustomers.Address2, MyCustomers.PostCode, MyCustomers.County, MyCustomers.Country, MyCustomers.RowCount, MyCustomers.CustomerID, MyCustomers.Title, MyCustomers.FirstName, MyCustomers.LastName, MyCustomers.Designation, MyCustomers.LandLine, MyCustomers.Mobile, MyCustomers.Email, MyCustomers.FAX);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: marc_s thanks for your help, yes i have added the ID and it works, but how do i use stored procedure? program works fine without SP but I would like to use SP